# what I have to do to declare a variable in "App.js" in React.JS and use this variable in "return()" into the App function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, null, onclick

[the image of the final project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2OZ.png)

- when I click on one of the orange buttons it should print the "p1" variable to the console but the value of this variable is Null
  I don't know why this variable gives me that error and I want to use it in the onClick function inside the buttons.

  import img_1 from "./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg";
  import img_2 from "./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg";
  import img_3 from "./images/illustration-box-desktop.svg";

  function App() {
  const p1 = document.querySelector("p1");

  ```
  return (
    <>
      <img src={img_3} alt="img_3" className="img_3" />

      <div className="container">
        <div className="imgBox">
          <img src={img_1} alt="img_1" className="img_1" />
          <img src={img_2} alt="img_2" className="img_2" />
        </div>

        <div className="textBox">
          <h1>FAQ</h1>
          <div className="questions">
            <div>
              {/* the value of p1 is null */}
              {/* because it can't get document.querySelector(".p1") above */}
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log(p1);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="p1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p2">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p4">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p5">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  ```

  }

  export default App;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error here, simply a misunderstanding on your behalf I presume. Your issue is trying to use `document.querySelector` within the react component.

Simple Answer:
Use `useRef` instead as below. Also, checkout the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for a better understanding.

Full Answer:
When the compoent first renders, `document.querySelector` is run before you return the element with the class "p1". Therefore it hasn't yet been redered on the page. There `document.querySelector` will fail to find the element, returning null instead.

```js
function App() {
  const p1 = React.useRef(null);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <img src="" alt="img_3" className="img_3" />
      
      <div className="container">
         <div className="imgBox">
          <img src="" alt="img_1" className="img_1" />
          <img src="" alt="img_2" className="img_2" />
        </div>

        <div className="textBox">
          <h1>FAQ</h1>
          <div className="questions">
            <div>
              {/* the value of p1 is null */}
              {/* because it can't get document.querySelector(".p1") above */}
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log(p1);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p ref={p1} className="p1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p2">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p4">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p className="notactive p5">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-bom/WJB/C/RVkBpU7ic7qopGc/CSWjj1aZhZLykucHKCZuT9h881Uh8VdvEioA6L0vQ/Tsaw1uK2Pnj312c17g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-HBhuJNLkfYh0Z++tgfKYCstQZzgQmMbAfK4FvzxHrUYqfI+FRnXeBn1ZXu+1NSGWissxE2ipI+eKaoRbRV2W4Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Targeting a class with a `querySelector` string needs a dot:

```js
function App() { const p1 = document.querySelector("p1");
// should be:
function App() { const p1 = document.querySelector(".p1");
```

If you want to store a variable in a React component, I suggest you look into [useState()](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate) instead of a query selector:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
    const [fillerText, setFillerText] = useState(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis."
    );

    return (
        // other stuffs
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => console.log(fillerText)}>
                How many team members can I invite?
            </button>
            <p className="p1">{fillerText}</p>
        </div>
        // other stuffs
    );
}
```